# Fstab mount smbfs share for user noauto asking for password via GUI

Tags: gui, fstab, cifs

I'm trying to do a connection for my work computers d: from my laptop.
Altough to have direct access to the disk I need to use the computers administrator account. And I would not like to save the password for the administrator account in fstab file on my laptop.

```
# work share
//172.16.8.2/d$         /home/user/domain/d   smbfs username=administrator,domain=domain,user,rw,noauto  0  0
```

This is how it looks in the terminal

```
$ mount ~/npn/d
Password:
```

And I get the thing mounted in no time.

Now to the trouble: If I try to "click" the d "drive" in the file browser I'm met by this error box:

Unable to mount d
Password: mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

Logic, because the graphical interface can't throw me a password login promt like the terminal.

Is there any way for me to solve this problem, to just be able to "click" on the unmounted d drive and get a GUI passpromt thrown?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. I believe you are being asked the SAMBA password, so add in the password to the `fstab` entry:

   ```
   username=administrator,password=admin_samba_password,domain=domain,user,rw,noauto
   ```

   If you do not want the password in `fstab`, use a credentials file as [described in this blog entry](http://anothersysadmin.wordpress.com/2007/12/17/howto-mount-samba-shares-in-fstab-using-a-credential-file/).

   Run the following commands as root, but change the path as you see fit:

   ```
   mkdir -p /path/securedir
   chmod 0700 /path/securedir
   chown root /path/securedir
   ```

   Then create a file `/path/securedir/fileshare` with the following contents:

   ```
   username=yourusername
   password=yourpass
   ```

   Now append `credentials=/path/securedir/fileshare` to your fstab entry.
2. Your other option, and the one I use, is [`autofs`](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs). It takes a little time to configure, but it is mounted on demand and is invisible to the end user.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to quote relevant parts from the linked content? Especially with the credential file? The reason the credential files are superior to throwing it into the `fstab` is because `fstab` can usually be read by anyone, whereas the credential file can be protected extra.

Comment: Depends on what the OP wants, I can flesh out the answer

Comment: Hmm, I would like to get a GUI prompt for the password (and not have it in yet another file). :-/

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann - Ask your own question. Posting in the comments does you little or no good.

Comment: That question would  be a duplicate to this one (it also asks for a GUI prompt), though ... I guess I'll try, maybe something did change in the last two years.

Answer (score 1):

> bodhi.zazen: I believe you are being asked the SAMBA password

Yes it's the samba password that is being asked for in the terminal. There doesn't seem to be a good solution to bringing a GUI popup to enter the SAMBA password. And since I **don't** want to save the password in either credential file, fstab or individual autofs files. I will live with it as it is and start a terminal and write:

```
mount ~/npn/d
```

and then enter the SAMBA password in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Faced with the same problem.
For me mounting a CIFS share from a NAS

Problems being faced...

1/ mount has no method of specifying a password handler (such as used by sudo, ssh, etc)

2/ Putting the password in the fstab makes it readable by any one on the system at any time!

3/ mount can be given a password as a option but that means it is on the command line and for a brief moment the password is visible to anyone on the system.  But that appears the only way.

4/ mount will only accept options when it is run as root, but if "mount.cifs" is made SUID, then you don't need to run mount as root!

Current Solution.

Given "/usr/libexec/openssh/x11-ssh-askpass" available on most systems (see http://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/anthony/crypto/passwd_input.txt for alternatives).  And "/etc/fstab" defines the mount point a "/mnt/cifs".

Then this works as a GUI mount command, but requires 2 passwords...  your SUDO (login) password and your CIFS password.

```
SUDO_ASKPASS=/usr/libexec/openssh/x11-ssh-askpass sudo -A \
   mount -o "password=$(/usr/libexec/openssh/x11-ssh-askpass 'CIFS Password')" /mnt/cifs
```

UPDATE:  If you make /sbin/mount.cifs SUID you can do away with the mount and the /etc/fstab (though you may like to keep the fstab to allow you to umount it).

```
/sbin/mount.cifs -o "user=username,pass=$(/usr/libexec/openssh/x11-ssh-askpass 'CIFS Password')"  //machine/share /mnt/cifs
```